# GetCurrentThreadId returns different threadId

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I call the mentioned windows API. But it returns a different thread id than the id returned by `_beginthreadex`. My code is following,

```
ThreadTest *_threadTest = new ThreadTest();
Thread *_thread = new Thread(StartRoutineForThread,_threadTest);
```

Constructor for Thread class is,

```
ThreadWin::ThreadWin(void * (*_startRoutine)(void *), void * _argument, bool _isJoinable)
{
        unsigned int _threadAddress;
        unsigned int threadID = _beginthreadex(
                                    NULL,
                                    0,
                                    (unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *))_startRoutine,
                                    _argument,
                                    0,
                                    &_threadAddress
                                );
}
```

`StartRoutineForThread` function which is the start routine for thread is following,

```
void* StartRoutineForThread(void* _argument)
{
    ThreadTest *_threadTest = (ThreadTest*)_argument;
    _threadTest->Run();
    return NULL;
}
void ThreadTest::Run()
{
    this->threadID = ::GetCurrentThreadId();    
}
```

Now in the constructor of class `Thread` the value of the variable `threadID` differs from the value of class `ThreadTest`'s variable`threadID` that I get from the `Run` function. But the `Run` function was called from the function that I specified when I have created the thread. So the `Run` function is running under the same thread that I have created. But then why `GetCurrentThreadId()` returns different value than what was returned by `_beginthreadex` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `_beginthreadex` doesn't return thread id. Thread id is stored in `_threadAddress`, the last parameter of `_beginthreadex`. Its return value is thread *handle* (like `CreateThread`), not id.

Comment: What is the difference between the handle and ID?

Comment: @kalkin handle is used to manipulate. DC, GDI Object, Thread, Process... If you have a handle of these, you can manipulate it by calling function directly. (For example, `HDC hdc = ...; TextOut(hdc, ...);`. So, handle don't need to be valid globally. it need to be valid only in one process which have the handle. However, id cannot be used to manipulate. It is just for distinction, and it is valid and unique globally, even inter-process. But you can't manipulate "the object (thread, process, ..)" by id. you should have appropriate access rights, and get handle from id (`GetThreadId` function...

Comment: @kalkin For more information about id (especially thread id), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686746.aspx

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, `_beginthreadex` returns thread **handle**, and it is not the same as thread ID.